# Is there a way to show UIStatusBar, but still hide the green "Touch to return to call" button?

Tags: iphone, uistatusbar

Because it's seemingly impossible to find an Apple-authorized way to access carrier signal strength, I'm considering leaving `UIStatusBarHidden` set to `false` so that the signal bars will still show. The only problem then becomes that the ugly green "Touch to return to call" button pops up in a call. I'd rather keep the status bar without the green bar. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: Lol, Apple doesn't want you to know the signal strength for a good reason. How bad would it have been if you could see the numbers change on the iPhone 4 when you transition from death grip to 'recommended' grip.

Comment: Indeed. As for this case, I simply want to relay what is already known and displayed without showing another UI element. Essentially, can the green bar be divorced from the status bar?

Comment: There might be a hidden API somewhere. I have never needed an iPhone specific feature so I've not really researched them at all. You could request that apple add it: bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Just FYI, the private framework is at https://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks/tree/master/SpringBoard, for those unconcerned with legit AppStore distro. SBStatusBarController has Double Height Status Bar goodies. Too bad I'm trying to play by the rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an Apple Authorized way?

No.

Comment: Found those tasty github private frameworks, but apparently they're a big Apple no-no. Blast.